# How do I format a signed integer to a sign-aware hexadecimal representation?

Tags: formatting, integer, rust

My initial intent was to convert a signed primitive number to its hexadecimal representation in a way that preserves the number's sign. It turns out that the current implementations of `LowerHex`, `UpperHex` and relatives for signed primitive integers will simply treat them as unsigned. Regardless of what extra formatting flags that I add, these implementations appear to simply reinterpret the number as its unsigned counterpart for formatting purposes. ([Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=813f0a2f055c5877b001502d8e452389&version=stable))

```
println!("{:X}", 15i32);           // F
println!("{:X}", -15i32);          // FFFFFFF1   (expected "-F")
println!("{:X}", -0x80000000i32);  // 80000000   (expected "-80000000")
println!("{:+X}", -0x80000000i32); // +80000000
println!("{:+o}", -0x8000i16);     // +100000
println!("{:+b}", -0x8000i16);     // +1000000000000000
```

The documentation in [`std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html) is not clear on whether this is supposed to happen, or is even valid, and [`UpperHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.UpperHex.html) (or any other formatting trait) does not mention that the implementations for signed integers interpret the numbers as unsigned. There seem to be no related issues on Rust's GitHub repository either. (**Post-addendum notice:** Starting from `1.24.0`, the documentation has been improved to properly address these concerns, see issue [#42860](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42860))

Ultimately, one could implement specific functions for the task (as below), with the unfortunate downside of not being very compatible with the formatter API.

```
fn to_signed_hex(n: i32) -> String {
    if n < 0 {
        format!("-{:X}", -n)
    } else {
        format!("{:X}", n)
    }
}

assert_eq!(to_signed_hex(-15i32), "-F".to_string());
```

Is this behaviour for signed integer types intentional? Is there a way to do this formatting procedure while still adhering to a standard [`Formatter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this formatting procedure while still adhering to a standard [`Formatter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html)?

Yes, but you need to make a newtype in order to provide a distinct implementation of `UpperHex`. Here's an implementation that respects the `+`, `#` and `0` flags (and possibly more, I haven't tested):

```
use std::fmt::{self, Formatter, UpperHex};

struct ReallySigned(i32);

impl UpperHex for ReallySigned {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let prefix = if f.alternate() { "0x" } else { "" };
        let bare_hex = format!("{:X}", self.0.abs());
        f.pad_integral(self.0 >= 0, prefix, &bare_hex)
    }
}

fn main() {
    for &v in &[15, -15] {
        for &v in &[&v as &UpperHex, &ReallySigned(v) as &UpperHex] {
            println!("Value: {:X}", v);
            println!("Value: {:08X}", v);
            println!("Value: {:+08X}", v);
            println!("Value: {:#08X}", v);
            println!("Value: {:+#08X}", v);
            println!();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I swear access to the formatter options didn't used to be there, but it looks like they've been there since 1.5.0, so I dunno what I was thinking.

Comment: Well [`flags()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.flags) was always there, it's just that "which bit is what" is not really documented...

Answer (score 2):

This is like [Francis Gagné's answer](/a/44712309/60075), but made generic to handle `i8` through `i128`.

```
use std::fmt::{self, Formatter, UpperHex};
use num_traits::Signed;

struct ReallySigned<T: PartialOrd + Signed + UpperHex>(T);

impl<T: PartialOrd + Signed + UpperHex> UpperHex for ReallySigned<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let prefix = if f.alternate() { "0x" } else { "" };
        let bare_hex = format!("{:X}", self.0.abs());
        f.pad_integral(self.0 >= T::zero(), prefix, &bare_hex)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:#X}", -0x12345678);
    println!("{:#X}", ReallySigned(-0x12345678));
}
```