# Hexadecimal formatting with padded zeroes

Tags: rust

When formatting integer types to hexadecimal strings, I cannot get it to pad the numbers with zeroes:

```
println!("{:#4x}", 0x0001 as u16) // => "0x1", but expected "0x0001"
println!("{:#02x}", 0x0001 as u16) // => "0x1", same
```

Comment: Your second question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44711012/1233251)

Comment: Actually, the first `println!` prints ` 0x1` (with a leading space) and the second one prints `0x01`. You just have to consider that the `0x` is counted in the requested length. `println!("{:#06x}", 0x0001 as u16);` will print `0x0001`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Keep in mind that the leading `0x` is counted in the length so if you want something printed as `0x0001` then the length is really going to be 6, not 4.

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:#06x}", 0x0001u16);
}
```

This prints `0x0001` as you wanted.